# Generate downloadable link in Odata item service

Tags: sitecore-services-client, odata

I want add some media and files in sitecore and expose it through Odata Item Service to so that an external system can download the file from sitecore.
But when we request any item over Odata, getting the raw value as the response in the FieldValues.
For Images:

```
"Image": "<image mediaid=\"{06CFC2DC-4C4A-433F-8930-E3A0FC32BD2C}\" />",
"Image__Url": "/-/media/Images/test.ashx",
"Image__Alt": "none"
```

For Files:

```
"File": "<file mediaid=\"{3CC98823-4976-4E6E-BB55-AFF7A885BCDC}\" src=\"-/media/3CC9882349764E6EBB55AFF7A885BCDC.ashx\" />
```

How we can replace this response with an actual downloadable link for the Image and File Types.

Comment: After getting this response, you can try using the src attribute value and prepend it with the site name. You should be able to get the File URL then. For media you can prepend the site url with the Image__Url

Comment: @SumitUpadhyay- the I can make a valid Image request by adding sitece url before Image__Url. But for File this is not working. Eg: the url for file will be like http://mysite.com/-/media/3CC9882349764E6EBB55AFF7A885BCDC.ashx and getting a 404. When I tried downloading manually from content editor the url was http://mysite.com/sitecore/shell/download.aspx?file=E0AFF7A35F80470393A90C259B23F874 and you can see the ID is also different

Comment: For File, you can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980704/sitecore-create-file-download-link

Comment: @SumitUpadhyay- How we can insert the valid downloadable url in the Odata response?

Comment: Please post the files url here - the files url should open/download the pdf in browser , first test that

Comment: @jojo , Did you able to resolve this? i would think we can create some controller-oData function-endpoint that returns such URL?